# Include Style From NPM Package Component Into WebComponent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, web-component, vue-cli-3

I am building a webcomponent package using Vue CLI 3 and single file components. We have a shared package our-awesome-shared-controls that contain basic site components such as a collapsible container.

Inside my component, I import and reference the collapsible container and wrap my content in it. When I build as an app the styles from the imported components are included and everything looks great, however; when I target `wc` (WebComponent) using the vue-cli the style for the imported component (collapsible container) are not included.

Is there a way for me to tell the vue cli that it should include those styles? If not would there be a way to import those styles? The imported components have their style set to scoped so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.